# Can't Access HTTPS on AWS EC2

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, https, amazon-ec2

I have been testing setting up SSL on AWS EC2 instance, i have followed couple of tutorials which advised of creating d balancer and setting up the correct ports.

I have added HTTPS to my security group inbound and outbound, restarted apache server, rebooted the instance and still can't access my website through HTTPS, and the HTTP still works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IIS you also have to add a binding to the website in the IIS manager, so that the web server knows to listen for and respond to https requests. There should be an equivalent configuration you need to do in apache - have you done that?

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/bind.html

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment, that was definitely the issue, i am kind of a beginner and none of the tutorials mentioned anything about adding Listen 443 to the apache ports.conf.

Really appreciate your help